# Exclude footer from bibliography

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancyhdr` in a document I'm writing and what I want to do is place numbering (which is placed in the footer) only in the main body of the document. Not in the bibliography. In other words I just want to remove the footer (and only the footer, not the header) from the pages covered by the bibliography. How can I achieve that?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{Header of every page}
\cfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{EndDocument}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\harvard}{{\sf harvard}}
\newcommand{\Harvard}{{\sf Harvard}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\fontsize{11}{12}
\selectfont


\input{./title.tex}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

Here is the main body of the document. I think there is no need to place it.

\label{EndDocument}
\newpage 
\bibliography{report}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just issue `\fancyfoot{}` *after* `\newpage`. This clears the (entire) footer only from that page onward in the `fancy` page style, while still maintaining the header. In this case, `\cfoot{}` would also suffice.